# How do I rename the Domain for the Default Directory for a Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I signed up for an Azure account with my email address. Just assume it is `myemail@mycompany.com`. I see the domain for that default directory as **Default Directory (myemailmycompany.onmicrosoft.com)**. I see this at the top right corner of the azure portal.

I have a few questions about this:

1. How can I rename the domain from `myemailmycompany.onmicrosoft.com`
   to `mycompany.onmicrosoft.com`?
2. Does directory mean **Active
   Directory**?
3. How can I navigate to the page which lists all the users in that default directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I rename the domain from myemailmycompany.onmicrosoft.com to
>   mycompany.onmicrosoft.com?

I don't think it is possible to change the name of a directory. Not sure if you want to do this but you can assign a custom domain (e.g. mycompany.com) to your directory. See this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain.

> Does directory mean Active Directory?

Yes.

> How can I navigate to the page which lists all the users in that
>   default directory?

In Azure Portal, click on Azure AD icon and then "Users".

[image]